# coreutils that are utf aware?

Tags: unicode, coreutils, cut

When I used `cut` today, I found out it doesn't treat a UTF-8 character as a character, but 3 characters because it's 3 bytes long.

This seems to be generally true for many tools.

Are there versions of the `coreutils` that are UTF-8 aware?

My `locale` output:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Here is when `cut` doesn't work

```
echo 哈哈 | cut -c 2-
��哈
```

The right output should be

```
哈
```

if `cut -c` worked with multibyte characters.

Comment: Did you set your `locale` properly?  What's the reading of `locale` (w/o arguments) command invocation?

Comment: I have updated with the locale.

Comment: OK, can you also add some example of your `cut` command line?

Comment: Can confirm this on Ubuntu 10.04 with `echo ßßßß | cut -c 2-` -> `�ßßß` (`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`)

Comment: The sad thing is that, 3 years later, this is still true in Ubuntu 13.10...

Comment: Another example: `cut -d $(echo -e "\\u007C\\u001C")`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GNU coreutils do understand UTF-8 in general. For example `echo 哈哈 | wc -m` correctly outputs `3` in a UTF-8 locale (note that the option is `-m`, not `-c` which for historical reasons means bytes).

This is a bug in `cut`. Looking at the [source of `cut`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/cut.c), `cut` on characters is simply not implemented: the `-c` option is treated as a synonym of `-b`.

A workaround is to use awk. GNU awk copes with UTF-8 just fine.

```
awk '{print substr($0,2,length)}'
```

Comment: It would be worth filing a bugreport (even if it ends up being a duplicate) to annoy the coreutils maintainers into actually fixing bugs like this, rather than just adding stupid hacks and toy utilities that nobody needs...

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a bug in your build/version of `coreutils`.  I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat but not on Fedora 15.

```
[patches@holocene ~]$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 15 (Lovelock)
[patches@holocene ~]$ rpm -q coreutils
coreutils-8.10-2.fc15.x86_64
[patches@holocene ~]$ echo 哈哈 | cut -c 2-
哈
[patches@holocene ~]$ sudo chroot /mnt/maverick
root@holocene:/# grep DISTRIB_DESC /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"
root@holocene:/# dpkg-query -s coreutils | grep Version
Version: 8.5-1ubuntu3
root@holocene:/# echo 哈哈 | cut -c 2-
��哈
```

If you're also using Ubuntu, you can report a bug to the Ubuntu `coreutils` packagers by running the following command:

```
apport-bug coreutils
```

**Update:**  Gilles points out in the comments that this is a bug in the upstream version of `coreutils` that Fedora has patched.  [You can find their patch here](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=coreutils-i18n.patch;h=6e10f376996b64f538259091a524df2249b653fb;hb=HEAD) if you would like to try to patch it yourself to get it working.

Comment: I just looked at the source, and it's an upstream bug that Fedora apparently patched. The upstream source simply makes `-c` an alias of `-b`.

Comment: @Gilles:  Interesting.  I linked to Fedora's patch in my answer in case someone wants to try and fix it for themselves.

Comment: Link is broken.